# Performance on Node.js vs Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, babeljs

so I'm working on an open source project that currently is using an older version of node.js (0.12.7) and I want to get them up to the point of using the newer node version (5.0.1). They are however using Babel so I'm not certain whether or not it's worth it to convert to the native operations atm. My question is, is there a performance upgrade from converting all babel code to native node.js for version 5? Why or why not? Thanks again.

Comment: If you are compiling babel, then you are producing "native" code. That's what the babel compile step does. Now, to figure out if there is a difference between babel's compiled code and code that you write yourself, you will have to actually run your own benchmark. Any answer on which will perform better depends on the exact code in question, which you haven't supplied.

Comment: @Tyrsius crap...I was afraid somebody would say that. It's a massive project, and from what I can make of it most of it is for imports and registration...let me try editting what I have up above.

Comment: The code babel produces from compilation is pretty solid. It adds very little in terms of extra work. Especially if most of it is `import`s, its going to be a one-time "onload" cost. I am not sure re-writing a "massive" project to get rid of a compilation step is worth much, if anything.

Comment: alright. Thanks for the input. I'll take your word for it.